# What is a good size (in bytes) for a log file?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am using the  python [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#simple-examples) modules [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#rotatingfilehandler), and you can set the maximum size of each log file. What is a good maximum size for a log file? Please give your answer in bytes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

My default logging setup:

```
RotatingFileHandler(filename, maxBytes=10*1024*1024, backupCount=5)
```

Comment: In other words: 10 MiB.

Comment: copy this one, maxBytes=10485760

Comment: I love this answer because 10 MiB is not really a special value, but finding the best value is so specific and complicated. 10 MiB is as good as it gets to start playing around, and may as well become a Schelling point only for having been posted here :)

Comment: it should be noted that often *building* a value is far more often more useful that straight up *using* the resulting value.

Answer (score 21):

As the other answers have said, there is a no hard and fast answer.  It depends so much on your app and your environment. Here's some guidelines I use.

For a multi-user app on a typical server:
Configure your logging to generate no more than 1 or 2 entries per user action for production, and then rotate it daily.  Keep as many days as you have disk space for, or your data retention/privacy policies allow for.  If you want auditing, you probably want a separate solution.

For a single-user app:
Try and keep enough information to diagnose anything weird that might happen.  No more than 2 or 3 entries per user action though, unless you are doing batch operations.  Don't put more than 2MB in a file, so the user can email it you.  Don't keep more than 50MB of logs, because it's probably not your space you are wasting here.

Comment: Good point about emailing logs, that actually tipped the scales on a decision I had to make. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Size isn't as important to me as **dividing at sensible chronological points**.  I prefer one log file per day, however, if the file won't open with any notepad program you have at your disposal, it is too big and you might want to go with hourly logs.

Comment: But don't use the Windows `notepad.exe` as a measurement tool, because it's really bad at opening anything even slightly largeish (at least up to Windows XP, maybe that got better).

Comment: Joachim: Still, if that's all you have then you'd rather want a log file you can open.

Answer (score 3):

It completely depends on the external variables of the system.  For instance:

- Are you running on an embedded device whose only external storage is a 1MB SD card, or do you have full access to a 1TB hard drive?
- Are you logging each time you enter/exit a function, or are you only logging one or two caught exceptions throughout the whole system?
- Is the purpose of these logs to be sent back to the developer for support?  A 1kb log file isn't going to help you much, but you probably don't need 200MB of logs for a single support issue.

Without these kinds of details, there is no good answer to your question (and there might not be a good answer even *with* these details).

Comment: I'm logging each time I enter/exit a function in debug mode. I find it useful so in that case what should I set the size of the log file? Functions are crud functions for database via SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @Ivan: Since it's running in debug mode, you probably have some room to tweak settings as necessary.  Start out with a value like 250k, and if your application is too database-intensive to fit its log in there, increase the size as necessary.