# what's the limit of logfile's size in python

Tags: python, logging

In python, what's the limit of log-file's size by default? 10M, 2G, or some other limit?

Where can I find this information in the API?  I know the rollback of `RotateFileHandlers`, it can configure. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521082/what-is-a-good-size-in-bytes-for-a-log-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum size of a file is filesystem dependant. There's nothing about it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that the basic logging FileHandler

> By default, the file grows indefinitely.

See the link below for more information on the different handlers that are built into python, and how they work.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html